# Trying to understand e.PreventDefault and e.StopPropogation behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a `handleSubmit` function which checks the validity of the form and then sets the state of the `validated` flag to true, based on the result of `form.checkValidity`.

The default of `validated` is false and after it passes the form's validity check, it is set to true using `setValidated`.

Question is, when I use `e.StopPropogation`, does this stop the rest of the code from executing?

The value of `validated` prints false at the end of the `handleSubmit` function, which suggests the `setValidated` hook was not called (but console.log continues to print?). In addition, looking at my console output, the program jumps back to line 50 and the value of `validated` there is true.

I don't quite understand why line 50 executes after `handleSubmit` and why would the value of `validated` there be true?

```
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form"
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button"
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col"
import { useState } from "react"


const Register = () => {

    const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
    const [visitorId, setVisitorId] = useState('');
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [lastFourDigits, setLastFourDigits] = useState('');
    const [mobileNumber, setMobileNumber] = useState('');
    /*const [email, setEmail] = useState(''); Note: for future addition */
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState('');
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('');

    /*const[visit, setVisit] = useState([]);*/

    const visit = {
        firstName : firstName,
        lastName : lastName,
        lastFourDigits : lastFourDigits,
        mobileNumber : mobileNumber,
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate : endDate
    }
    

    const addVisit = async (visit) => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/register-scheduled-visit',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(visit), 
        })

   /* const addVisitor = async (visit) => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/register-new-visitor',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(visit), 
        })  */

    }
    console.log("Validated outside handleSubmit: " + validated)
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
       
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        console.log("Form validaity in handlesubmit: " + form.checkValidity())
        console.log("Validated inside handleSubmit first line: " + validated)
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }

        /*setVisit({...visit, startDateofVisit: startDate, endDateOfVisit: endDate, visitorId: '1', oneTimeUse: false});*/
        console.log(visit);
        setValidated(true);
        console.log("Validated in handlesubmit second line: " + validated)
        /*event.preventDefault();*/
      };
    console.log(visit);
    console.log('First Name: ' + firstName);
    console.log('Last Name: ' + lastName);
    
    return (
        <div className="register-form">
            <h1>Register a visitor</h1>
            <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{textAlign:'left'}}>
            <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridFirstName">
                <Form.Label>First name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    required 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="First name" 
                    defaultValue={firstName} 
                    onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}/>
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Please provide a name</Form.Control.Feedback>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridLastName">
                <Form.Label>Last name</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    required type="text" 
                    placeholder="Last name" 
                    defaultValue={lastName} 
                    onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}/>
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Please provide a name</Form.Control.Feedback>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form.Row>

            <Form.Group controlId="formGridLastFourDigits">
                <Form.Label>Last four digits of identification</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    required
                    placeholder="123A"
                    defaultValue={lastFourDigits}
                    onChange={(e) => setLastFourDigits(e.target.value)}/>
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Please provide the last four digits of your identification</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group controlId="formGridMobileNumer">
                <Form.Label>Mobile number</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    required
                    placeholder="Mobile number"
                    defaultValue={mobileNumber}
                    onChange={(e) => setMobileNumber(e.target.value)} />
                    <Form.Text id="mobileHelp" muted>
                        A QR code will be sent to this number for entry.
                    </Form.Text>
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Please provide your mobile number</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridStartDate">
                <Form.Label>Start date of visit</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    required 
                    type="date"
                    defaultValue={startDate}
                    onChange={(e)=> setStartDate(e.target.value)}/>
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid"></Form.Control.Feedback>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEndDate">
                <Form.Label>End date of visit</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control 
                    required 
                    type="date"
                    defaultValue={endDate}
                    onChange={(e)=> setEndDate(e.target.value)}/>
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid"></Form.Control.Feedback>
                </Form.Group>
            </Form.Row>

            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Register
```

Console output

```
log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
Register.js:50 Validated outside handleSubmit: false
Register.js:67 {firstName: "", lastName: "", lastFourDigits: "", mobileNumber: "", startDate: "", …}
Register.js:68 First Name: 
Register.js:69 Last Name: 

Register.js:54 Form validaity in handlesubmit: false
Register.js:55 Validated inside handleSubmit first line: false
Register.js:62 {firstName: "", lastName: "", lastFourDigits: "", mobileNumber: "", startDate: "", …}
Register.js:64 Validated in handlesubmit second line: false
Register.js:50 Validated outside handleSubmit: true
Register.js:67 {firstName: "", lastName: "", lastFourDigits: "", mobileNumber: "", startDate: "", …}
Register.js:68 First Name: 
Register.js:69 Last Name:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question is, when I use e.StopPropogation, does this stop the rest of the code from executing?

No, it stops the event from propagating and triggering other `submit` event listeners higher up the DOM (NB: you are unlikely to have any). (`preventDefault` on the other hand, would prevent the default behaviour of the form: Submitting the form data to the `action` and navigating to a new page generated by the response).

> The value of validated prints false at the end of the handleSubmit function, which suggests the setValidated hook was not called (but console.log continues to print?). In addition, looking at my console output, the program jumps back to line 50 and the value of validated there is true.

The `handleSubmit` has closed over the `validated` constant. It will never change it's value.

`setValidated` will queue up a change to the component's state. Once the event loop is free (i.e. some time after `handleSubmit` has finished running, assuming the browser doesn't navigate to a new page due to the form submission) the component will be rerendered. This will call the `Register` function again and the `validated` constant belonging to this invocation of the function will have the new value.

> I don't quite understand why line 50 executes after handleSubmit and why would the value of validated there be true?

That is the rerender described in my previous paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do have a few questions about what you described above.

Comment: (1) Does this mean setValidated is only queued (and not actually executed) in the handleSubmit function? And validated is only set to true on the next instance of the Register component? (2) Is this normal form behaviour? Because based on above, if a user were to submit a blank form, the validated flag gets updated to true on the next render, which theoretically marks the 'new' form as validated=true (which is not correct).

Comment: (1) Yes (2) It is normal **React** behaviour. And yes, storing the results of testing if the form is valid during a submit event doesn't seem like the right solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the help Quentin, much appreciated. Regarding having the setValidated hook being put in the handleSubmit function, I actually got that off the react-bootstrap official page here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/ (down at the Validation section, first example). Perhaps it's because it's being shown in a live code snippet.

Comment: It looks like an oversimplified example. You need to think about what you actually want to happen when then submit button is clicked.